# Ubuntu reinstall on PC with Ubuntu + Windows; no option to replace Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have Windows and Ubuntu 12.04 (not working) on my computer and I decided to reinstall Ubuntu.

After I booted into the Live USB I don't see the option of replacing the installed Ubuntu with the new one I'm about to install. I can only choose between replacing Windows or managing partitions myself.

Some people on the Ubuntu forums and Ask Ubuntu (on existing threads & questions) say that this may be caused because Windows is taking up all partitions and I need to manage all those partitions myself. However, I'm not really happy to manage partitions myself, since I have GRUB on my PC, and deleting it would be a serious problem.

Actually, before this install with only two options, I tried another install, however, during that time there were three options and one of them was to replace Ubuntu with the about-to-install one. However, I decided to quit during installation **at the point where the three options showed up**, but pressing the Quit button just doesn't work and my cursor was a spinning wheel (which tells me to wait). I got impatient after one or two minutes and powered off my PC by pressing the power button directly.

After that, no option of replacing Ubuntu showed up during this second install. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem a few weeks ago with 12.04 (and also a not working 13.04 install). I understood I installed Ubuntu on a Windows partition, which was the reason why Ubuntu didn´ t recognize it.

I manually installed on the partition, and installed GRUB on an external HDD. GRUB was indeed deleted on my HDD. I then rebooted from the HDD and could boot into my fresh install, where I could set up GRUB properly. This is a bit messed up and I cant guarantee it will work but it did for me.

There are other ways to install GRUB a posteriori, for example using a liveCD and Boot-repair